# Is the form in create view already bound?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I have this code

```
class ObjectCreate(CreateView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
```

I want to know that is this form already bounded to object instance and i can use form.save or i have to bound it to model instance manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the form in `form_valid` is bound.

You can see this by looking at the code for [`ProcessFormView`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/views/generic/edit.py#L125).

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
```

You can see that a bound form is instantiated by `self.get_form(form_class)`, and the `form_valid` method is only called if the form is valid.

Note that the [`ModelFormMixin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/views/generic/edit.py#L66) used by the `CreateView` saves the object by default -- depending on what you are trying to do, you may not have to override `form_valid`.

Comment: ACtually im my normal operation i am not overiding anything but in my ajax request i am overiding the form valid so that if request is ajax then i can save the form and return my custom json repsonse. Is that k or i can do that without overirding the method

Comment: Overriding `form_valid` to return a json reponse for ajax requests sounds like a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can [take form class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py) and ask for [bounded](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms):

```
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    if form.is_bound:
        ...
```